# App for Interval Timing for Sprints

Tags: app

I've got a training regime that works very well which involves:
- Run/Sprint for 150m
- Rest/Walk for 30seconds
- Repeat 30x

It's very difficult to monitor and keep track of progress.  I wanted to use some app that could record a monitor my intervals and make comparisons per week, however all the HIIT apps don't let you time the run/sprints so it's hard to work out if you are making any improvements.

I have downloaded 20 applications and only one meets the requirements, however it's very easy to reset and delete the entire set.

- Start Timer / Start Sprint
- Finish Sprint / Press Interval - elapsed time is recorded
- 30 second countdown begins
- (Repeat)

Comment: So you want a stopwatch and interval timer combo app? I don’t believe anything like that exists. The reason why is because an interval timer will only work on predetermined intervals. The only thing I can imagine that would help you is to run with your phone in hand while a stopwatch is running and simply glance at it when you need to.

Comment: Are you ios or android too, which would matter here.  I am using android and haven't found an app yet.  I was hoping for one...